# Onkeypress enter event not firing

Tags: javascript

My onkeypress event is not working on the search bar on my website. Here's my javascript and html code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("SearchText").value = getParameterByName("s");

    var a = document.getElementById("SearchLink");

    a.onclick = function() {
        search();
    }
}

function search() {
    var searchResultsUrl = "/search/";
    document.location.href = searchResultsUrl + "?s=" +
    document.getElementById("SearchText").value;
    return false;
}

function getParameterByName(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)')
        .exec(window.location.search);

    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

And here's the  html code:

```
<input type="text" id="SearchText" onkeypress="if(SearchText.keyCode==13)search()" />
```

Comment: jsfiddle of issue: http://jsfiddle.net/mgvPs/

Answer (score 4):

A text box does not have a `keyCode` property - that is a property of an event object. Try this instead.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="SearchText" />
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var textbox = document.getElementById("SearchText");
    textbox.value = getParameterByName("s");

    ... snip ...

    textbox.onkeypress = function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            search();
        }
    };
}

... snip ...
```

[A fixed fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/mgvPs/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The `SearchText` variable in your onkeypress scriptlet will be undefined. I suggest defining your event handler in Javascript, like so:

```
SearchTextbox = document.getElementById("SearchText");
SearchTextbox.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
        // Handle key press event here
    }
}
```

For your reference:

KeyboardEvent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent

element.onkeypress: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onkeypress

Edit: changed `event` param name as suggested.

Comment: you generally want to name the event parameter something other than `event` as this shadows the `window.event` global variable that IE uses.